# Raw AngularJs markup appearing in Google search results page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, caching, search-engine

We just updated portions of our website with AngularJS - particularly the login page.  When I look at the search results in Google, the cached page and the small snippet it displays automatically is the raw Angular markup.  So, lots of `{{model.username}}`, `{{model.errorMessage}}`, etc.

I won't link the results since it's too embarrassing.

Any idea of how do get Google to actually store the page as rendered vs. the raw HTML?

Answer (score 1):

SEO for angular is a really big question/issue depending on your perspective. I would start by reading http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html and http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html to get you started.

To sum up your primary options:

- change your routing system to use the hashbang (`#!`). Then sites like google and facebook will convert the hashbang to `_escaped_fragment_` before querying your page. This gives your server an opportunity to return different html.
- use a service like http://prerender.io which will pre render and cache rendered versions of your site for you, which will be provided to google in place of your site.

There are still issues with things like sharing to `reddit` and `stumbleupon` for example, as they are lazy and don't want to develop to cater to angular based sites. So for certain circumstances you will have to get creative.

---

Update: One thing we have done on a recent project is look at the various user agents to determine if crawling systems are asking for page information. This way we can serve what ever we like.

Answer (score 1):

It would be wonderful if you would convert your embarrassment into a community service for all of us by testing something, since you are seeing a condition few people admit to or want to reproduce themselves. :)

Google is known to be relatively (or very, depending on who you ask) good at ignoring hidden content. They implemented this way back when people used to keyword-stuff content by using blocks that were either set to "display: none" or had a tiny/unreadable/white-on-white font.

What you're seeing is a problem for more than just SEO, so I'm suggesting this because things like prerender.io are great but they only solve that one piece. What about users who simply have slow browsers? Well, it turns out Angular has a great solution for this called `ngCloak`. It hides things like template content fields (ngModel mappings and bindings, expressions, etc) until Angular is ready to fill them in itself.

It's very easy to implement this; you just need a small block of CSS (in an early-loaded file, or embedded directly into your HTML page):

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and then you apply the `ngCloak` directive to items that are affected, or to a high-level parent (like your ng-view DIV):

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-cloak>
    <!-- Page content here -->
</div>
```

This works kind of like a no-js target, but specifically for AngularJS.

You'll still want something specific to give Google that is actually *good* material, but at least with the above you can filter out everything else.